# Generators functions only yields first item

Tags: python, generator

I have some data in the following format:

```
data = """

[Data-0]
Data = BATCH
BatProtocol = DIAG-ST
BatCreate = 20010724

[Data-1]
Data = SAMP
SampNum = 357
SampLane = 1

[Data-2]
Data = SAMP
SampNum = 357
SampLane = 2

[Data-9]
Data = BATCH
BatProtocol = VCA
BatCreate = 20010725

[Data-10]
Data = SAMP
SampNum = 359
SampLane = 1

[Data-11]
Data = SAMP
SampNum = 359
SampLane = 2

"""
```

The structure is:

1. `[Data-x]` where x is a number
2. `Data =` followed by either `BATCH` or `SAMPLE`
3. Some more lines

I am trying to write a function that yields a list for each 'batch'. The first item of the list is the textblock containing the line `Data = BATCH`, the following items in the list are the textblocks containing the line `Data = SAMP`. I currently have

```
def get_batches(data):
    textblocks = iter([txt for txt in data.split('\n\n') if txt.strip()])
    batch = []
    sample = next(textblocks)
    while True:
        if 'BATCH' in sample:
            batch.append(sample)
        sample = next(textblocks)
        if 'BATCH' in sample:
            yield batch
            batch = []
        else:
            batch.append(sample)
```

If called like this:

```
batches = get_batches(data)
for batch in batches:
    print batch
    print '_' * 20
```

it, however, only returns the first 'batch':

```
['[Data-0]\nData = BATCH\nBatProtocol = DIAG-ST\nBatCreate = 20010724', 
 '[Data-1]\nData = SAMP\nSampNum = 357\nSampLane = 1', 
 '[Data-2]\nData = SAMP\nSampNum = 357\nSampLane = 2']
____________________
```

Wheras my expected output would be:

```
['[Data-0]\nData = BATCH\nBatProtocol = DIAG-ST\nBatCreate = 20010724', 
 '[Data-1]\nData = SAMP\nSampNum = 357\nSampLane = 1', 
 '[Data-2]\nData = SAMP\nSampNum = 357\nSampLane = 2']
____________________
['[Data-9]\nData = BATCH\nBatProtocol = VCA\nBatCreate = 20010725', 
 '[Data-10]\nData = SAMP\nSampNum = 359\nSampLane = 1', 
 '[Data-11]\nData = SAMP\nSampNum = 359\nSampLane = 2']
____________________
```

What am I missing or how do I improve my function?

Comment: If you're trying to parse files that look like that, take a look at the [`ConfigParser` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html).

Comment: Aside: instead of `iter([some listcomp here])`, you can write `(some genexp here)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @F.J explained, the real issue with your code is that you're not yielding the last value. However, there are other improvements that can be made, some of which make solving the last-value problem easier.

The big one that stood out to me on my first look at your code is the two `if` statements checking for `'BATCH' in sample`, which can be combined into one.

Here's is a version that does that, as well as using a `for` loop on a generator, rather than `while True`:

```
def get_batches(data):
    textblocks = (txt for txt in data.split('\n\n') if txt.strip())
    batch = [next(textblocks)]
    for sample in textblocks:
        if 'BATCH' in sample:
            yield batch
            batch = []
        batch.append(sample)
    yield batch
```

I'm unconditionally yielding `batch` at the end, because there's no situation where you can get there with `batch` empty (if `data` was empty, the initialization of `batch` near the start will raise `StopIteration`).

Answer (score 6):

You only yield a batch when you find the beginning of the next batch, so you will never include the last batch of the data.  To fix this you will need something like the following at the end of your function:

```
if batch:
    yield batch
```

However just doing this won't work.  Eventually the `next(textblocks)` inside of the loop will raise a `StopIteration` so no code after the `while` loop can be executed.  Here is one way to get this to work with just a minor change to your current code (see below for a better version):

```
def get_batches(data):
    textblocks = iter([txt for txt in data.split('\n\n') if txt.strip()])
    batch = []
    sample = next(textblocks)
    while True:
        if 'BATCH' in sample:
            batch.append(sample)
        try:
            sample = next(textblocks)
        except StopIteration:
            break
        if 'BATCH' in sample:
            yield batch
            batch = []
        else:
            batch.append(sample)
    if batch:
        yield batch
```

I would suggest just looping over `textblocks` with a `for` loop instead:

```
def get_batches(data):
    textblocks = (txt for txt in data.split('\n\n') if txt.strip())
    batch = []
    for sample in textblocks:
        if 'BATCH' in sample:
            if batch:
                yield batch
            batch = []
        batch.append(sample)
    if batch:
        yield batch
```